# Postgres group by with aggerate (last comment in a conversation across all conversations)

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I want to get the last comment in a conversation between two people.

My table structure as follows:

```
                                                          Table "public.comments"
   Column    |            Type             |                       Modifiers                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer                     | not null default nextval('comments_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 body        | text                        | not null                                              | extended |              | 
 target_id   | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 target_type | character varying(255)      |                                                       | extended |              | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null                                              | plain    |              | 
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null                                              | plain    |              | 
 user_id     | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              |
```

My Attempt:

```
SELECT
  comments.id,
  max(SELECT id comments.created_at),
  CASE 
  WHEN user_id   = 1 THEN CONCAT(user_id,'_',target_id) 
  WHEN target_id = 1 THEN CONCAT(target_id,'_',user_id)
  END
FROM comments
WHERE
  comments.user_id = 1
  OR
  (comments.target_type = 'User'
  AND
  comments.target_id = 1)
  GROUP BY 
    CASE 
    WHEN user_id   = 1 THEN CONCAT(user_id,'_',target_id) 
    WHEN target_id = 1 THEN CONCAT(target_id,'_',user_id)
    END
```

So I figured out how to group the comments but how to order by created_at and get the latest id and information is where I'm stuck.

Comment: What's `target_id`? Is that the other user in the conversation? Also, it would help if you posted an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the schema defined and a small amount of sample data that shows an example of the query above.

Comment: To me your query confuses more than helps. Post sample data and desired result.

Comment: The target_id is the other person in the conversation or visa versa. Since you can be either that target_id or the user_id I have to group by either or.